# Getting error while adding Facebook SDK in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk, android-build

I am working on a project where I need to implement facebook login. For that purpose I followed the steps from the developer [website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) as mentioned. But unfortunately getting build error after adding`'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'` in `build.gradle`as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.facebook"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

**Error log which I am getting:**

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0.

     Required by: ExampleApp:app:unspecified

> No cached version of com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0 available for offline mode.
> No cached version of com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0 available for offline mode.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue which I am facing right for a couple of days. I am really helpless and stuck up with the solutions. Any kind of suggestions would be much useful to fix my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your log gives the answer:

> No cached version of com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0 available for **offline mode**.

Gradle is in offline mode, so it cannot download a new version of your library.
Go to Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle
and disable "Offline work".

Preferences can be accessed from here:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to go to preferences in android studio?

Comment: On OS X: in the top bar at the "Android Studio" item (or with CMD+",")
[edit] On all platforms: through the icon with the wrench in your icon bars in the top.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to access the Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `repositories` in this gradle file as you should have one "global" `build.gradle` so remove this entry from module's grade file. And you should also check what `repository` is set there as it should be `jcenter()` not `mavenCentral()` as the latter is replaced with `jcenter()` for some time now.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```